# [zod-i18n]zod error message is always undefined on serverside of Next.js

Tags: next.js, zod

I'm using zod and zod-i18n. it works out on client side, but not on server side

/pages/api/hello/index.ts

```
  const params = {
    name: fields['company[name]'][0]
  };
  const schema = z.object({
    name: z.string().min(1).max(30),
  });
  const validation = schema.safeParse(params);
  if (!validation.success) {
　　　　　　　console.log("issues", validation.error.issues)
    const errors: Record<string, string> = validation.error.issues.reduce(
      (acc, curr) => ({ ...acc, [`${curr.path.join('.')}`]: curr.message }),
      {},
    );
    return res.status(422).json({ errors });
  }
```

This results is below.

```
  issues: [
    {
      code: 'too_big',
      maximum: 30,
      type: 'string',
      inclusive: true,
      exact: false,
      message: undefined, => wrong value
      path: [Array]
    }
  ],
```

why does this occur? any help?

Comment: What is the value of `params` in your code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem by this code

```
i18nextInit({
  lng: 'ja',
  resources: {
    ja: { zod: translation },
  },
});
z.setErrorMap(makeZodI18nMap({ t: i18nextT }));
```

Comment: Where did you import the i18nextT  from

Comment: i18nextT is the t function exported from i18next which is `i18next.t`